# The bot does not respond to the command

Tags: python, discord.py

The bot does not respond to the command, how can this be fixed?

```
@bot.command(command=['sendmessage'])
async def sendmessage(ctx, message: str):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    await channel.send(str)
```

I tried to replace command with message_handler, but I got an error

```
line 117, in <module>
 async def sendmessage(ctx, message: str):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you provide full error message?

Comment: You should be passing `message` instead of `str` in the `send()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to call the data type of your variable, not the variable itself.

The variable you **should** be calling is the `message` variable. When you call `str`, you are referring to a `string` datatype that hosts values. The following is shown below:

```
@bot.command(command=['sendmessage'])
async def sendmessage(ctx, message: str):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    await channel.send(message)
```

Your function defines the `message` variable as a string. I believe you may be misunderstanding whether `message` or `str` is the variable you are looking for.

Comment: it still doesnt responding

Comment: @RainWon I've attempted to reproduce your problem using the code I've provided, but the snippet seems to work on my end. Do you perhaps know the error name your interpreter gives you when executing?